# Clustering of polygons on map using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, clustering, maps

There is a plugin for Leaflet to cluster the markers.The result looks like so. Result:

[image: Result]

If I like something to do to show clusters of circles and polygons?

For example, when you hover over a cluster it shows the ground on which he considers the number. I would like to have this mesh of polygons is always on display and she was the color of the color circle. Something in concept. Wanted result:

[image]

Any idea experts this system?

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Would constraining it so the mesh is a rectangular grid be acceptable?

Comment: Hello Kirk! No. I am interested in the following: when you hover over the cluster - it is outlined (as shown in the pic 1). I want this cluster grid to always be displayed and cluster colors (like pic 2)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are you trying to do this using the plugin or code?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.

Comment: You can use `markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {  map.addLayer(L.polygon(a.layer.getConvexHull())); });`  https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/README.md#clusters-methods